# How to merge two source files easily?

Tags: c#, version-control, merge, diff

I am working with another colleague in C# in VS2005 in a not very complex project. However, we have no version control system, we send each other our last version and copy the changes into our own files.

We now have to merge both files (most of the project is a single form file) into a last version of the project.

Any suggestions? Maybe trying diff tools? It must be done quickly and probably learning how to use complex revision control programs is not doable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll spare you the lecture on not using version control, but your best bet is to try and use a differencing tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to compare the differences of the 2 files and manually merge the changes that each of you has made into a single file.

If you have the common file that you both started with before you each made any changes, then you can use a 3-way merge feature to generate a file that has both of your changes in it.

It was pointed out to me that WinMerge does not offer a 3-way merge, so refer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460198/best-free-3-way-merge-tool-for-windows) for finding a tool that supports it.

Comment: Minor quibble: WinMerge does not support 3-way merge. It can accept a third "output file" parameter, but not a "common ancestor" or "base" file. The most common free easy-to-use 3-way merge tool I've seen for Windows is TortoiseMerge, installed with TortoiseSVN (or TortoiseGit, or any of the other derivatives I assume).

Answer (score 2):

We use [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) - we have found that to be an excellent compare and merge tool.

I understand the need for speed to produce your final version of the code now.

However, if you are planning to start another project it really is worth investing the time to set up a source control system.  You'll save that time in spades over the course of the project!

Answer (score 1):

Try [SourceGear DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/). Some members of my team even use it instead of the standard compare/merge tool from Visual Studio.

Comment: I am trying winmerge. Is DiffMerge superior to winmerge?

Answer (score 1):

I think WinMerge is great for diffing and merging files.

However, I would *definitely* recommend that you get yourself some kind of source control system. CVS, Subversion, Git, Mercurial, whatever!!! It doesn't really matter which you choose, just get one. You will almost immediately get return on that investment in time, and you will also learn about something that is crucial in all serious software development.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it, however I need a temporal quick solution and winmerge looks great :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

> WinMerge is an Open Source differencing and merging tool for Windows. WinMerge can compare both folders and files, presenting differences in a visual text format that is easy to understand and handle.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Craigy - Be my guest. I don't know how to describe it better than they did, and trying to present that here would mean practically copying their page, including the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Because I just found this question while looking for something completely different, and noticed the assertion that WinMerge doesn't do 3-way merge.

This used to be true, but WinMerge is under new management, and has had 3-way merge for some time now. At the time of this post, the current WinMerge version is 2.16.2, available at [WinMerge.Org](http://winmerge.org/downloads/) (setup kits for 32 and 64 bit, as well as source code).